# Read input from a cocoa/foundation tool console?

Tags: cocoa, console, foundation

I wonder if Objective-C/Foundation has any special commands for reading user input from the console. Since it has NSLog for output maybe there is something else I could use instead of the scanf command.

I need to read some numbers (user input) into my tool. What is the best way to get these input in types like double or int? And how do I get user input into an NSString?

Answer (score 9):

I was bored earlier and came across this issue of 'use scanf'. since I wanted to see if I could do it without dropping into c, the following came up:

```
NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
while (1)
{
    NSData* data = [input availableData];
    if(data != nil)
    {    
        NSString* aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
 }
```

I'm sure somebody could optimize this and make it nicer (this was used for a really simple PoC CLI tool)

Comment: That gets most of the way, but doesn't parse the numbers. Also, don't forget to release what you have allocked.

Comment: thats just a snippet. but you're right, I should've added that for completeness.

Comment: This works for files (app < data) but not for pipes (cat data | app) so better use [input readDataToEndOfFile]

Comment: I tried this, but it only allows me to enter one character at a time, or better put, as I type, I only see the first character of my input.

Answer (score 4):

The only real Cocoa support for input is [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileHandle/fileHandleWithStandardInput)'s `fileHandleWithStandardInput`. It isn't really more useful than `scanf()` if you ask me. But for getting input into specific types, well, that's pretty much NSFormatter's *thing*. There are already a lot of predefined formatter types for standard things, and you can make a custom formatter if you have more specialized needs. So if you need something a little more than `scanf()`, just read in the data (either as bytes with `scanf()` or data with NSFileHandle) and make an NSString from it and you can format it to your heart's content.

Comment: fileHandleWithStandardInput records ALL keystrokes, even the invisible ones like moving the input cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing like `scanf` ([which is a good thing](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&num=20&q=scanf+insecure)). You can slurp data from stdin using [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/); for interactive input, `fgets` is better. You'll then want to use either `strtol`/`strtoul`/`strtod`, NSScanner, or NSNumberFormatter to convert the input to numeric types.