# Read Console Input As NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way using the command line console to read a user typed value as an NSNumber, or do I have to read the input as a c-type integer and convert to a NSNumber object?

(e.g.)

```
NSLog(@"Enter Age:");
scanf("%d", &userAge);
```

gary

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869802/read-input-from-a-cocoa-foundation-tool-console/1641715#1641715.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSNumber is actually a class, not a primitive. (Unlike, say, NSInteger which is just a typedef'ed integer or long, depending on which machine you're running.)

I think you're going to have to read it in and then do [NSNumber [numberWith](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...]