# How to get inout to an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, macos, foundation

How to get input from an NSString as `scanf ("%@", &str);` doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read input from a cocoa/foundation tool console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869802/read-input-from-a-cocoa-foundation-tool-console)

Comment: *To* an NSString, or *from* an NSString? Your subject says one, and your question the other, and it makes a big difference in the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf will read into a C string and not into a NSString (as far as I know). So, to do what you're trying to do you need to first read your input into a C string (i.e. str) and then make that into an NString as follows

```
myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
```

By the way, you don't need to pass the address of str i.e. &str if str is an array. Simply do:

```
scanf("%s",str);
```